# how to exclude a password validator

Tags: python, django

***I answered my own question below. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.***
I created a custom password validator called 'NoUsername' which I put in the settings file under the 'AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS'. If I'm using validate_password() to validate the password the user entered, how do I exclude my custom 'NoUsername'? Thanks.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.password_validation.validate_password

The reason is because I want to use 'NoUserName' for registering but not for changing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it seems to have worked. Sorry for wasting anyone's time.

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import (validate_password,
 password_validators_help_texts, get_default_password_validators)

validators = get_default_password_validators()
validators = validators[:-1]
validate_password(new_password, password_validators=validators)
```